# iOS Charts: Drawing data set with non-linear X-Axis

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

Trying to plot the line chart with non linear x-axis scale. The sample data set it
(5,100)
(10,200)
(15,100)
(10, 50)
(5, 100)

The result chart should draw a Rhombus but it does nothing. No line is displayed on the chart view. Does iOS Charts support non-linear X-Axis scale?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a shape with a linear axis, just to make sure Charts is setup correctly?

Comment: @Martin Muldoon: Yes. It does draw the line with linear x-axis.

Comment: iOS charts expects the x-axis data to be sorted as confirmed on [Charts GitHub](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/3717)